# Sometimes code work and soemtimes it does not work? Please review code

Tags: python-3.7

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
    return result


def get_factorial(k):
    if (k<2):
        result= 1
        return result
    else:
        result = k*get_factorial(k-1)
        print(result)
```

Comment: Please edit the question, format the code appropriately, provide a [mcve] or at least explanation how you’re calling these functions, what they should do, what results you expect and what results you get instead. And see the [help] on how to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RECTIFIED FACTORIAL PROGRAM**

```
 def get_factorial(k):
        if k == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return k * get_factorial(k-1)
```

**RECTIFIED TRI_RECURSION PROGRAM**

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if k > 0:
        result = k + tri_recursion(k-1)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
```

Just call either of these function with a legal integer value and `print()` their return values